# Python dictionaries searching

Tags: python, dictionary

I cant make code to search for a one certain value in more than one dictionaries. The dictionary look like this (sorry for the key names. Its in my native language):

```
{
    "Učitelia" : {
        "Mgr. Liana Smrečanová" : {
            "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Liana", "Priezvisko" : "Smrečanová", "Trieda" : "III. C"
        },
        "PaedDr. Mária Slováková" : {
            "titul" : "PaedDr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Mária", "Priezvisko" : "Slováková", "Trieda" : "IV. B"
        },
        "Mgr. Dominika Šimová" : {
            "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Dominika", "Priezvisko" : "Šimová", "Trieda" : "I. C"
        },
        "Mgr. Viera Šuchmová" : {
            "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Viera", "Priezvisko" : "Šuchmová", "Trieda" : "Septima A"
        },
        "PaedDr. Emília Uhláriková" : {
            "titul" : "PaedDr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Emília", "Priezvisko" : "Uhláriková", "Trieda" : ""
        },
        "Ing. Ján Valuška" : {
            "titul" : "Ing.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Ján", "Priezvisko" : "Valuška", "Trieda" : ""
        },
        "Mgr. Jana Vasilová" : {
            "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Jana", "Priezvisko" : "Vasilová", "Trieda" : ""
        },
        "PhDr. Ivana Veselá" : {
            "titul" : "PhDr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Ivana", "Priezvisko" : "Veselá", "Trieda" : "II. B"
        },
        "Mgr. Tatiana Volentier, PhD." : {
            "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "PhD.", "Meno" : "Tatiana", "Priezvisko" : "Volentier", "Trieda" : ""
        },
        "Mgr. Jaroslav Výbošťok" : {
            "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Jaroslav", "Priezvisko" : "Výbošťok", "Trieda" : ""
        }
    },

    "Vedenie" : {
        "Riaditeľ" : {
            "RNDr. Ivetta Vidová" : {
                "titul" : "RNDr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Ivetta", "Priezvisko" : "Vidová", "Trieda" : ""
            }
        },
        "Zástupcovia" : {
            "Mgr. Ľubica Knollová" : {
                "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Ľubica", "Priezvisko" : "Knollová", "Trieda" : ""
            },
            "Mgr. Miroslav Škrinár" : {
                "titul" : "Mgr.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Miroslav", "Priezvisko" : "Škrinár", "Trieda" : ""
            },
            "Ing. Jozef Výboh" : {
                "titul" : "Ing.", "druhy_titul" : "", "Meno" : "Jozef", "Priezvisko" : "Výboh", "Trieda" : ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if its too long.
I want to search for "Meno" in all "Zamestnanci". But when I search for it I only can find "Meno" in "Ucitelia" because "Vedenie" has another dictionaries to go through. When I tried to make code to search for all of it I didn't get anything for output.
So can someone help me please?
And **sorry** if my English is wrong.

This searched only in "Ucitelia":

```
for i in dict_.get("Učitelia"):
    if dict_.get("Učitelia").get(i).get("Meno") == "Liana":  
    end.append(dict_.get("Učitelia").get(i))
```

And this is what I tried:

```
for i in dict_:
    if dict_.get("Meno") != None:
        if dict_.get("Meno") == "Liana":
            end.append(dict_.get("Meno"))
            dict_ = reset_dict()
        break
    else:    
        dict_ = dict_.get(i)
        dict_a = dict_
        print("\na", dict_a)
        for a in dict_a:
            print("\n", a, dict_a)

            if dict_.get("Meno") != None:
                if dict_.get("Meno") == "Liana":
                    end.append(dict_.get("Meno"))
                    dict_ = reset_dict()
                break
            else:   
                dict_ = dict_.get(a)
                dict_b = dict_
                print("\nb", dict_b)
                for b in dict_b:
                    print("\n", b, dict_b)

                    if dict_.get("Meno") != None:
                        if dict_.get("Meno") == "Liana":
                            end.append(dict_.get("Meno"))
                            dict_ = reset_dict()
                        break
                    else:
                        dict_ = dict_.get(b)
                        dict_c = dict_
                        print("\nc", dict_c)
                        for c in dict_c:
                            print("\n", c, dict_c)
                              
                            if dict_.get("Meno") == "Liana":
                                end.append(dict_.get("Meno"))
                                dict_ = reset_dict()
                            break
```

*dict_ is the dictionary up there*

I know it looks ugly but I'm only 12 yo and I don't have big coding experience

Answer (score 0):

I'd use recursion to search nested dictionary like this, something like this example (`dct` is your dictionary from the question):

The recursive generator `search_name` has two parameters - `obj`: object that is traversed and `to_find`: name that we are trying to find. The generator yields the key (full name + title) and value (the dictionary with additional info):

```py
def search_name(obj, to_find):
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if v.get('Meno') == to_find:
                yield k, v
            else:
                yield from search_name(v, to_find)

for k, v in search_name(dct, 'Ivetta'):
    print(k, v)
```

Prints:

```
RNDr. Ivetta Vidová {'titul': 'RNDr.', 'druhy_titul': '', 'Meno': 'Ivetta', 'Priezvisko': 'Vidová', 'Trieda': ''}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had the same def function but i didnt paste it here. I just needed the code to search for them so thank you